# How do I link the image logos to the matching tabs and content?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, wordpress-theming

How do I link the image logos to the price table below the image logos? I can not link the logos, so the price table change page/list when clicking on the logos? Can it be done with only html? :)

Link: https://defektskaerme.dk/priser/

[image]

Comment: Could you share the code you already have with us as a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: off course, but I do not have much code. The pricelist is just a shortcode from a plugin (stylish price list).

Code for one of the images:

<a href="defektskaerme.dk/priser/#1_1615814155"><img class="alignnone wp-image-1567 size-medium" src="defektskaerme.dk/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/…" alt="" width="300" height="300" /></a>

Shortcode for Pricelist:

<p style="text-align: center;">[pricelist id="1615814155"]</p>

Answer (score 0):

Click on the image and change URL links as below e.g for apple

```
https://defektskaerme.dk/en/#1564036204144-6e919b1d-df47729d-428ed02f-c30f
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9awNA.gif]

for en add this url before #

```
https://defektskaerme.dk/en/
```

for regular site add this url before #

```
https://defektskaerme.dk/
```

Comment: It is not a problem on the frontpage (another price table). It is only a problem on the page listed above. I use a new pricelist plugin which I want to copy to the frontpage when it works proberly, but I can not link that pricelist to the images? :)